# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError in Python(ver 3.10)

Tags: h5py, python-3.10

I use tensorflow ver 2.12.0 in python 3.10.0.

And I want to use '.h5' file.

This is Code and error.

```
**model = keras.models.load_model("./sourcecode/weight_forest_type.h5", compile=True)**
```

**error : UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 55: invalid start byte**

How to slove this in Python 3.10?
I must use this h5 file.

Downgrading the 'h5py' package version, latest to 2.10.0, that is the solution of this problem.
But, I have python 3.10